# include xaml in xaml on xamarin forms with prism mvvm view model. Cannot resolve INavigationService

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I want to include a back button inside selected pages. For some reason i have called it "Breadcrumb", please assume its called "BackButton" :).

The issue is that the navigation service does not get pulled through in the ioc.

Here's the following code with the exception i am coming across:

**Main Page XAML** - *notice the local:BreadcrumbControl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="Test.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Views">

    <StackLayout>
        <local:BreadcrumbControl x:Name="Breadcrumb" />
    </Stacklayout>
<ContentPage>
```

**Breadcrumb Control XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="Test.Views.BreadcrumbControl">

    <Button Text="Back" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="NavigationPage/ManageFoodGroupsPage" />

</ContentView>
```

**Breadcrumb Page View Model**

```
public class BreadcrumbControlViewModel : BindableBase
{
    INavigationService navigationService;

    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }

    // If i uncomment the navigationservice the following error occurs (*)
    public BreadcrumbControlViewModel(/*INavigationService navigationService*/)
    {
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
    }

    private void Navigate(string name)
    {
        navigationService.GoBackAsync();
    }
}
```

**(*)**

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "Test.ViewModels.BreadcrumbControlViewModel", name = "(none)".
>
> Exception occurred while: Resolving parameter "navigationService" of
>   constructor
>   Test.ViewModels.BreadcrumbControlViewModel(Prism.Navigation.INavigationService
>   navigationService).
>
> Exception is: NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>
> ---
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving Test.ViewModels.BreadcrumbControlViewModel,(none)
>
> Resolving parameter "navigationService" of constructor
>   Test.ViewModels.BreadcrumbControlViewModel(Prism.Navigation.INavigationService
>   navigationService)

**App.cs Container/Resolver registration**

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<BreadcrumbControl, BreadcrumbControlViewModel>();

Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
```

How do i go about including a common back button style thing (driven by a view model) in a Xamarin Forms Prism MVVM application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of navigation in Xamarin.Forms (page based), the INavigationService only works for ViewModels that belong to types of Page.  It must be a page, otherwise, you have no way to navigate.  If you must have the INavigationService in this ContentView's VM, thenn you must register the INavigationService with the container, but it may not behave as you would expect since it will be working off of the Application.Current.MainPage, instead of the proper Page.

Comment: #Starstruck - Thanks Brian, great talk you did on Prism. I had noticed it was not possible to embed a page inside the XAML and that's why i resorted to the View. What's your approach of getting reusable bits like this? eg. A back button placed in lots of pages... while having it bound to a model :)

Comment: I have gone about this a different way and created a baseviewmodel with some of the more common navigation bits.. I guess i will now have to figure out how to use resources instead which should solve the problem :D

Comment: ANother approach to getting the navigation service is to create a new interface called INavigationServiceAware, and then override the COnfigureViewModelLocator and then provide a custom implementation for resolving objects. You can see a sample here https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Unity.Forms/PrismApplication.cs#L26

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any of the code for the other registrations you have done. Have you properly registered the NavigationService? In your setup, you should register it in your App.cs before registering the code that needs it.

Also, you should use **ContainerControlledLifetimeManager**. This essentially implements it as a singleton (assuming you want the same NavigationService passed throughout your app). This is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx)

```
Container.RegisterType<NavigationService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Well, it's just that Prism seemed to do that for me for the view models before, it's just that it doesn't deal with passing it into view models instantiated within a view.

Comment: I guess because it doesn't use registertypefornavigation, it's not going to inject it for me... i'll try and set up my own, thanks